# Are HCP and Primitive Hexagonal Unit Cell the same thing?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

In **HCP**, the [2D] ***Hexagonal packed layers*** are arranged in **ABAB** form. The same happens in **Primitive Hexagonal Unit Cell**. So does that mean they are the same? If not what differentiates one from the other?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE. It's unclear what you are trying to ask. Please edit your post to explain clearly what your question is.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: Where is the difference between a crocodile and a dolphin?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I made changes to the question. I hope now it's okay.

Comment: @Zenix NO! it's not a homework question, edited the question just now. Could you answer the question now??

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I edited the question, is it okay now??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the same happens in primitive hexagonal unit cell

Herein lies the gap in your concept: **The same does not happen in primitive hexagonal unit cell**. Here's an image to clear things up

[image][image]

The left one is a primitive hexagonal unit cell whereas the right one is a HCP lattice. To use your terminology, a simple primitive cell has packing of the type **AAAA..** whereas a HCP cell has packing of the type **ABAB..**

I highly recommend reading your textbook or referring to some more material on solid state chemistry, such as [this SlideShare presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/md5358dm/crystalography-29164496) on basic crystallography.

Comment: So from 2d hexagonal packed layers we can make 1) HCP and 2)CCP but not Primitive Hexagonal Unit Cell??

Comment: Yes you can. How to do so is an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: the second part of the question, can Primitive Hexagonal Unit Cell be made in the same way by arranging the 2D hexagonal layers in AAA type??

Comment: The answer to this last question of yours is already here on this page, a few lines above.

Comment: There is no such thing as an HCP lattice in terms of classifying symmetry. HCP is a primitive hexagonal structure with two atoms in the primitive cell (one per asymmetric unit). See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/134572