# What is the difference between primitive Hexagonal unit cell and Hexagonal closed packing HCP

Tags: physical-chemistry

There are 14 types of Bravais crystal lattices (Primitive + Centered) in 3D. Every solid in this universe is made by the unit cells of these lattices.

> [image: Bravais lattice]

With the help of these Bravais lattice can HCP be formed?.
*Is there any relation between Hexagonal unit cell and Hexagonal close packing*
As we see that Hexagonal unit cell exists only in primitive AAA form then how can HCP ABA be formed from it .

> 

**Primitive Hexagonal unit cell**

> [image: primitive Hexagonal unit cell]

**Hexagonal closed packing HCP**

> [image]

If there is a clear distinction then Should HCP also be placed among 14 Bravais lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the help of these Bravais lattice can HCP be formed?

Yes. One choice of unit cell for HCP is a primitive hexagonal cell with two atoms per unit cell. If you place the first atom on the origin, the second will be at (1/3 2/3 1/2). Here is a 3D view of the situation and some more information: http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss1/crystalstructure/structures/hcp/hcp.php

> Should HCP also be placed among 14 Bravais lattice?

No, because it is already in there, just hiding a bit. If you look further into it, the space group is #194, P$6_3$/mmc, see http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/large/194az1.htm